# How to skip to the latest item in an infinite async stream in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

While processing a stream, we are only interested in the latest item. Stream items might arrive faster than we can process them, so on each iteration we want to skip to the latest item in the stream. This is what I've tried (please see the full program here: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e4871a7719de189859dacee87c093d9))

```rs
while let Some(mut item) = stream.next().await {
   let mut cx = Context::from_waker(futures::task::noop_waker_ref());
   while let Poll::Ready(Some(i)) = stream.next().poll_unpin(&mut cx) {
      item = i;
   }
   
   println!("processing event {item}");
   // some lengthy processing 
}
```

It almost works, but sometimes the output doesn't seem right.

```
processing event 1
latest event: 3
latest event: 4
latest event: 6
processing event 6
latest event: 8
latest event: 10
latest event: 12
processing event 12
latest event: 14
latest event: 15
latest event: 18
processing event 18
...
```

In this run for example, the first line of output is `processing event 1`, which I don't understand why it is not preceded with `latest event: 1`.

Is something wrong with this code? Or if you can provide a better solution to this problem, I'll be thankful!

**Edit:** Works fine on computer. The output issue seems to be related to the Rust Playground.

Comment: Maybe 1 wasn't the latest item, for example because the channel was almost full and sending 2 blocked? Anyway, you don't handle waiting for items correctly.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What's the correct way to handle waiting for items?

Comment: Start with actually waiting for them and not just sleeping in hope they'll come.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The sleeping part is just simulating a lengthy process. In the actual program, items will come while we are doing the processing

Comment: And they always do? You never need to wait for them?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, If there's only 1 item in the stream, my understanding is that polling it again yields Pending, and we'll continue processing the single item

Comment: But if there are zero items, it will return `Pending`, and you will process the latest one again.

Comment: I don't know what Chayim is getting at, but it looks fine to me. The only issue is that a future returning `Pending` doesn't necessarily mean that it won't immediately return `Ready` when called again, but this seems as good as you'll get inside the rust async machine. For specific streams (like a channel) this is probably fine. Your setup allows for the consumer to check the channel while the producer is in the inner loop, so processing a number that isn't "latest event" is normal (it's the latest event from the consumer's POV).

Comment: If there are zero items in the stream, the outer `while let`  keeps waiting. If there is 1 item, the outer loop will consume it, the inner loop will do nothing. If there are more than 1 items, outer loop will consume first, and inner loop will drive it to the latest item

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the outer loop.